# Leitura via Socket

Tags: java, socket

Estou lendo strings enviadas via socket para um servidor em Java.
Recebo uma linha porém ao lê-la ela vem com quebra, parecendo duas linhas.
O que eu recebi deveria ser:
 **78780103554880201238560006d0d8**

Mas vem:
**7878

0103554880201238560006d0d8**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou utilizando é o seguinte:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Servidor {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket m_ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(2952);
    int id = 0;
    while (true) {
      Socket clientSocket = m_ServerSocket.accept();
      ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(clientSocket, id++);
      cliThread.start();
    }
  }
}

class ClientServiceThread extends Thread {
  Socket clientSocket;
  int clientID = -1;
  boolean running = true;

  ClientServiceThread(Socket s, int i) {
    clientSocket = s;
    clientID = i;
  }

  public void run() {
    // System.out.println("Accepted Client : ID - " + clientID + " : Address - " + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    try {
      BufferedReader   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter   out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
      while (running) {

            String clientCommand = in.readLine();
        byte[] b = clientCommand.getBytes();
        clientCommand = bin2Hex(b);

            System.out.println(clientCommand);
            if (clientCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
              running = false;
              System.out.print("Stopping client thread for client : " + clientID);
            } else {
              out.println(clientCommand);
              out.flush();
            }

    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


    public static String bin2Hex(byte bytes[]) {
        StringBuffer retString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
            retString.append(
            Integer.toHexString(0x0100 + (bytes[i] & 0x00FF)).substring(1));
        }
        return retString.toString();
    }


}
```

Não tenho muita intimidade com Java, creio que possa ser a maneira como leio ou a forma que defini os dados para leitura.

Alguma ajuda ?

Comment: Dica: Não precisa ficar colocando o nome da linguagem no título das perguntas, as tags que você escolhe já tem esse papel. Vale a pena dar uma lida aqui: [Quando se deve colocar o nome da linguagem no título?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/)

Comment: Ok, dica anotada, passarei a não fazer mais isso :)

Comment: Verifica se ajuda `clientCommand= clientCommand.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");` e depois é que fazes o `System.out.println(clientCommand);`

Comment: Mesma coisa, mesmo retirando as quebras de linha

Comment: Isso quer dizer que tu recebes 2 strings reais certo? primeira string "7878" e depois recebes "0103554880201238560006d0d8" certo? não recebes uma string que se divide durante a impressão?

Comment: O problema é este, o mesmo socket em outra linguagem eu recebo somente uma string, já este em java parece que são duas.

Comment: Só por curiosidade: executa isso System.out.println(clientCommand); antes de chamar a bin2hex.

Comment: Se eu fizer isso, aparece caracteres que não dá pra ler, a string vem em binário, daí o console fica doido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema parece ser com o `charset`. Force o `charset` para `UTF-8` nas seguintes linhas (34, 35):

```
BufferedReader   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
PrintWriter   out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```